# Where can I store a QAction(Group) ID?

Tags: qt

I see that `QButtonGroup`s let you throw in an integer when you do `buttonGroup->addButton` and then you can access this via the `buttonClicked` signal. This is handy for identifying which of of the buttons in the group was clicked. Why isn't there something similar for `QActionGroup`s? `QActionGroup`s have a `selected` signal, which will pass you back the `QAction` which you can use to identify which action was clicked, but I still want an associated `Id` so that I can use my `enum`. Is there anywhere inside of `QAction` that I can store such an integer, without it being a hack?

---

### Example usage:

```
toolsActGroup = new QActionGroup(this);
toolsActGroup->setExclusive(true);

selectToolAct = new QAction(QIcon(":/icons/custom/select.png"), tr("&Select"), toolsActGroup);
selectToolAct->setIconVisibleInMenu(false);
selectToolAct->setShortcut(Qt::Key_S);
selectToolAct->setCheckable(true);
selectToolAct->setStatusTip(tr("Select objects to modify or delete"));
selectToolAct->setProperty("tool", EditorScene::Select);
selectToolAct->setChecked(true);

// more actions here...

connect(toolsActGroup, SIGNAL(selected(QAction*)), this, SLOT(toolSelected(QAction*))); // use one signal for the whole (exclusive) action group

void EditorWindow::toolSelected(QAction* act) {
    // pass the value to the widget that needs it
    m_scene->setTool((EditorScene::Tool)act->property("tool").toInt());
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `QAction` is a `QObject`, which means you can set and get arbitrary key-value pairs on it using `QObject::setProperty` and `QObject::property`.

Comment: I suppose that's a reasonable solution. Thank you :) Much to learn about Qt yet.